# Spring AOP in separate project

Tags: spring-boot, aspectj, spring-aop

I've been playing around with `aspects` in my spring boot project using `spring-boot-starter-aop`. It's all working nicely and I have good test coverage with some of them leveraging whats offered in spring boot e.g. `@SpringBootTest`.

Since the aspects and related code would be useful across multiple different projects I wanted to extract this code into a separate "utility" project. Then import this utility project as a dependency.

As I understand stand it (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53680721/2440661)), a spring boot project should generally not be used as a dependency. Since I'm using `spring-boot-starter-aop` and also leveraging spring beans etc in my tests, this is a problem...

I'm just wondering on the best way to proceed. Any advice appreciated.

Thanks