# Maven install is failing while trying to look for dependent project

Tags: maven-3

I have order-core project which is dependent on tos-base. Here is my pom.xml. I tried all possible thing that is in stack overflow but I am still getting error.

I did following

mvn clean
mvn compile 
mvn compile dependency:tree
mvn clean install

Also, I tried to set MAVEN_OPT  with Xms and Xmx.

Also, I created the project again but same error.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.spectrum.sci</groupId>
    <artifactId>order-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>order-core</name>
    <description>Order Core</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <cxf.version>3.2.0</cxf.version>
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.spectrum.tos</groupId>
            <artifactId>tos-base</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
         </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.10</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-ws-security</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-rs-service-description</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2</version>
         </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
  </project>
```

Here is the error that I got:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] [1m--------------------< [0;36mcom.spectrum.sci:order-core[0;1m >---------------------[m
[INFO] [1mBuilding order-core 1.0[m
[INFO] [1m--------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------[m
[INFO] 
[INFO] [1m--- [0;32mmaven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:resources[m [1m(default-resources)[m @ [36morder-core[0;1m ---[m
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 4 resources
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] [1m--- [0;32mmaven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile[m [1m(default-compile)[m @ [36morder-core[0;1m ---[m
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 151 source files to C:\Users\P2932832\BPradhan\order-core\target\classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /C:/Users/P2932832/BPradhan/order-core/src/main/java/com/spectrum/sci/controllers/OrderController.java:[14,30] package com.spectrum.tos.model does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/P2932832/BPradhan/order-core/src/main/java/com/spectrum/sci/controllers/OrderController.java:[15,30] package com.spectrum.tos.model does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/P2932832/BPradhan/order-core/src/main/java/com/spectrum/sci/service/OrderDetailsService.java:[42,30] package com.spectrum.tos.model does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/P2932832/BPradhan/order-core/src/main/java/com/spectrum/sci/service/OrderDetailsService.java:[43,30] package com.spectrum.tos.model does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/P2932832/BPradhan/order-core/src/main/java/com/spectrum/sci/controllers/OrderController.java:[39,60] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class OrderRequest
  location: class com.spectrum.sci.controllers.OrderController
[ERROR] /C:/Users/P2932832/BPradhan/order-core/src/main/java/com/spectrum/sci/controllers/OrderController.java:[39,11] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class OrderResponse
  location: class com.spectrum.sci.controllers.OrderController
[ERROR] /C:/Users/P2932832/BPradhan/order-core/src/main/java/com/spectrum/sci/service/OrderDetailsService.java:[55,36] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class OrderRequest
  location: class com.spectrum.sci.service.OrderDetailsService
[ERROR] /C:/Users/P2932832/BPradhan/order-core/src/main/java/com/spectrum/sci/service/OrderDetailsService.java:[55,16] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class OrderResponse
  location: class com.spectrum.sci.service.OrderDetailsService
[INFO] 8 errors 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [1m------------------------------------------------------------------------[m
[INFO] [1;31mBUILD FAILURE[m
[INFO] [1m------------------------------------------------------------------------[m
[INFO] Total time:  21.704 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-03-13T13:52:35-06:00
[INFO] [1m------------------------------------------------------------------------[m
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal [32morg.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile[m [1m(default-compile)[m on project [36morder-core[m: [1;31mCompilation failure[m: Compilation failure: 
[ERROR] /C:/Users/P2932832/BPradhan/order-core/src/main/java/com/spectrum/sci/controllers/OrderController.java:[14,30] package com.spectrum.tos.model does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/P2932832/BPradhan/order-core/src/main/java/com/spectrum/sci/controllers/OrderController.java:[15,30] package com.spectrum.tos.model does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/P2932832/BPradhan/order-core/src/main/java/com/spectrum/sci/service/OrderDetailsService.java:[42,30] package com.spectrum.tos.model does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/P2932832/BPradhan/order-core/src/main/java/com/spectrum/sci/service/OrderDetailsService.java:[43,30] package com.spectrum.tos.model does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/P2932832/BPradhan/order-core/src/main/java/com/spectrum/sci/controllers/OrderController.java:[39,60] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class OrderRequest
[ERROR]   location: class com.spectrum.sci.controllers.OrderController
[ERROR] /C:/Users/P2932832/BPradhan/order-core/src/main/java/com/spectrum/sci/controllers/OrderController.java:[39,11] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class OrderResponse
[ERROR]   location: class com.spectrum.sci.controllers.OrderController
[ERROR] /C:/Users/P2932832/BPradhan/order-core/src/main/java/com/spectrum/sci/service/OrderDetailsService.java:[55,36] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class OrderRequest
[ERROR]   location: class com.spectrum.sci.service.OrderDetailsService
[ERROR] /C:/Users/P2932832/BPradhan/order-core/src/main/java/com/spectrum/sci/service/OrderDetailsService.java:[55,16] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class OrderResponse
[ERROR]   location: class com.spectrum.sci.service.OrderDetailsService
[ERROR] -> [1m[Help 1][m
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the [1m-e[m switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the [1m-X[m switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [1m[Help 1][m http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Comment: what is tos-base?

Comment: That's another project which contains basic functionality for all our projects. And order-core is dependent on this project . I am able to create jar file for tos-base project and it is in .m2/repository as well in my local repository.

Comment: can you add the error msg?

Comment: Edited the post to add error in the bottom of post.

Comment: Are you using a repository such as Nexus or Artifactory? Is the dependency com.spectrum.tos:tos-base:1.0:jar present on it? If not, did your install (`mvn install` on said project) first the tos-base dependency if you made change? (and last but not least, you may want to look at project reactor so that Maven knows how to compile correctly your project).

Answer (score 0):

try `mvn -U clean install` to reupdate the local repository from your remote repository, if the tos-base dependency is correctly installed under your local repository .m2/com/spectrum/tos, then you should check if the version 1.0 really contains the missing package maybe you should upgrade this dependency.

Comment: Here is the my local repository. C:\Users\P2932832\.m2\repository\com\spectrum\tos\tos-base\1.0>jar -tvf tos-base-1.0.jar and here are the files   2448 Fri Mar 13 11:00:54 MDT 2020 BOOT-INF/classes/com/spectrum/tos/model/Order.class 
   733 Fri Mar 13 11:00:56 MDT 2020 BOOT-INF/classes/com/spectrum/tos/BaseApplication.class
  2805 Fri Mar 13 11:00:54 MDT 2020 BOOT-INF/classes/com/spectrum/tos/model/OrderRequest.class. I have all classes and I created tos-base-1.0.jar today itself. I also did maven update project in the eclipse to sync. mvn -U clean install didn't help and got same error.

Comment: I tried to build another project that depends on tos-base . And I got the same error package com.spectrum.tos.builder does not exist. I tried to delete the folder in .m2/repository and created the jar again and got same issue. Not sure how to solve the problem.

Comment: I can see from your classes location (/BOOT-INF) that you are using a spring boot application as a dependency, this caused the compilation failure

Comment: this is an issue similar to yours https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53679361/cant-import-classes-intellij-showing-boot-inf-prefix-and-it-seems-to-be-relate

Comment: Wafa , Thank you very much. I tried by putting exec classifier , it worked. Since recommended approach is to modularize. I did the same and it worked as well.