# Maven package not found but classes exist in jar

Tags: java, maven

I have a package1 that has dependencies to package2.

The follow is pom.xml for package 2

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>data</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>data</name>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR4</spring-cloud.version>
        <checkstyle-maven-plugin.version>3.1.1</checkstyle-maven-plugin.version>
        <maven.compiler.release>11</maven.compiler.release>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--    POJO dependencies   -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-sql-mysql</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
            <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
            <version>6.13.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-data-firestore</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!--    Others  -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <!--    Testing     -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <!--     Check Style      -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${checkstyle-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <configLocation>checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>check</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <!--     Check Style      -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${checkstyle-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <configLocation>checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>

    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>github</id>
            <name>Package 2</name>
            <url>https://maven.pkg.github.com/company/package2</url>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>

</project>
```

In pom.xml package 1

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.7.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>api</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>api</name>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR4</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.company</groupId>
            <artifactId>data</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Google Cloud -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-pubsub</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-secretmanager</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
            <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
            <version>6.13.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--    Lombok  -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Testing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <version>1</version>
                    <projectId>GCLOUD_CONFIG</projectId>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

After run `mvn pacakge` and `mvn install`, the jar file of package 2 exists in ~/.m2/repository
And package 1 was able to find it. However, in package 1 when I try to import

```
import com.company.data.A;
```

The package `data` was not found, but surprisingly IntelliJ was able to find classes under com.company.data

For example, IntelliJ found com.company.data.A and com.company.data.B , but not **com.company.data** , I am very confused.

Comment: You can’t import a package! You import classes - a package is a namespace.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to import classes, let me provide more info

Answer (score 2):

Found [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53679361/cant-import-classes-intellij-showing-boot-inf-prefix-and-it-seems-to-be-relate), because spring boot package cannot be used for dependencies by default.